# PHPUnit test suite naming conventions

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

The [PHPUnit manual](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.pdf) highlights some conventions:

- The tests for a class `MyClass` go into a class `MyClassTest`
- The class `MyClassTest` live in file `MyClassTest.php`
- `MyClassTest` inherits from `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`
- Tests are public methods that are named `test*`

This will result in something like this folder structure:

```
├── src/
│   ├── classes/
│   │   ├── MyClass.php # Different
│   └── ...
├── tests/
│   ├── testcases/
│   │   ├── MyClassTest.php # Different
│   ├── bootstrap.php
│   └── ...
└── ...
```

... and this test case:

```
MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    testMyMethod() {
        // Code here.
    }
}
```

**My question**

I'm wondering if there is any reason why the naming used inside the test suite can't mirror the project's source code? For example, I'm thinking file names could match:

```
├── src/
│   ├── classes/
│   │   ├── MyClass.php # Same
│   └── ...
├── tests/
│   ├── testcases/
│   │   ├── MyClass.php # Same
│   ├── bootstrap.php
│   └── ...
└── ...
```

And if using PHP > 5.3, namespaces can be used to allow class names to match:

```
namespace MyProject\MyTests;

MyClass extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase { # The class name MyClass matches the class name used in my project's source.

    /**
     * @test
     */
    MyMethod() {  # The method name MyMethod matches the method name used in my project's source. 
        // Code here.
    }
}
```

Note the `@tests` annotation is used so method names can match.

Comment: The reason is the **convention**. Same as e.g. camelcase for class names. Nothing stops you to name your tests classes as you wish. It probably will look odd for other devs and will result with the opposite question - why not following conventions.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was thinking the same thing yet the appeal of having my tests exactly mirror my source makes sense to me. I mean, why name a test method and the method under test differently if you can name them the same?

Comment: It is slightly different rhetorical question. One of the *convention* for is to expose expected result, e.g. `testMyMethodDoesTheStuff()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And if using PHP > 5.3, namespaces can be used to allow class names to match:

There are reasons not to do this:

- It makes sense to have test and class under test in the same namespace
- Otherwise you need to import the class under test with a class alias to distinguish it from the test case:

  ```
  use MyProject\MyClass as MyActualClass;
  ```

> The method name MyMethod matches the method name used in my project's source.

This might sound appealing if you think of `testMyMethod` as the alternative, but this is *not* the convention. Instead you should use more descriptive test method names like `testThatMyMethodReturnsTrueIfFooIsBar`.

Comment: Regarding your second point (to use method names like `testThatMyMethodReturnsTrueIfFooIsBar`), is that because you might have more than one test method for each method under test? For example `testThatMyMethodReturnsTrueIfFooIsBar` and `testThatMyMethodDoesSomethingElse`

Comment: Yes, typically you will have one test method for the "happy path" and one or more for expected errors